# MySql  - Incorrect query results while checking for null values

Tags: php, mysql, database, null

My query is not giving proper results when I try to select user records that don't have email:

```
select * from users where email=''
```

And:

```
select * from users where email=NULL
```

Both give different results but neither give correct results. How can I get correct results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

```
select * from users where email IS NULL
```

Depending on HOW a user can have 'no e-mail', you should set the default value of the field to NULL and make the field nullable. Then if an insert is performed of a new record in that table, the e-mail will be NULL rather than empty.

Alternatively if you're already stuck with a mismatched table, try something like:

```
select * from users where LENGTH(COALESCE(email,'')) = 0
```

That'll give you all records with an 'empty' value for `email`, treating NULL as empty.

Comment: Exactly. For some reason in MySQL, NULL is not equal to NULL.
I've seen in my company codebase tons of queries in the form
`WHERE something IS NULL OR something = ''` because nobody remembers what is having "no value"

Answer (score 1):

null does not equal null.

you need to specify `IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Mysql treats both of them different

`email=''` checks for  blank values and `email=NULL` checks for null values that is why both of them giving different results.

You should use `is NULL` it checks both blank and null values.

```
SELECT *  FROM users WHERE email IS NULL
```